# Генерация выражения [1][2]..[k]

Tags: javascript

При прохождении некоторого цикла на каждой итерации необходимо проверять длину массивов, входящих в многомерный массив. А именно формируется выражение:

```
array[indexMultiArray].length , где
```

при 1й итерации `array[3].length`,
при 2й итерации `array[3][2].length`
и так далее. пока не закончатся массивы.

**Идея:** переменная indexMultiArray формируется как

```
indexMultiArray += '[' + index + ']';
```

В итоге при 1й итерации должно быть **indexMultiArray = [3]**, при 2й - **[3][2]**.

**Проблема:** в этому случае **indexMultiArray** - *строка*, и выражение array[indexMultiArray].length приобретает вид array"[3]".length, что конечно же ни к чему не приводит.

**Вопрос:** как сделать данную генерацию? Чтобы была не строка "[3]", а число [3]?

Выглядит этот кусок кода так:

```
 ...
  indexMultiArray += '[' + index + ']';
  if(element.length == array[indexMultiArray].length){..}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var indices = [];
...
indices.push(index);
var current = array;
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
  current = current[indices[i]];
}
if (element.length == current.length) {
  // ...
}
```